# During installation of ubuntu 12.04, gets stuck on booting screen?, Also, unable to upgrade from ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 12.04, installation, 10.10, upgrade

I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04 from DVD disk (clean install). But it gets stuck on the loading/booting screen.

On pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>, I get some errors as follows:

```
pwconv failed to change the mode of /etc/passwd- to 0600
```

And in the end this is shown, after which installation just gets stuck, I can do nothing except switching off the power source:

```
Starting crash report submission daemon [OK]
```

System:

> Dell Vostro 1440
>   Core i3 (2nd gen)
>   Intel HD Graphics

Currently I have Ubuntu 10.10 (Freshly Installed from http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/10.10/)  and wanted to upgrade to 12.04, but am unable to manually upgrade as authentication fails in update manager. Also, I am not able to download applications from Ubuntu software centre and it asks me to check my network/internet.

Answer (score 0):

Odd problem.

(You say 10.10 is installed and you're installing 12.04; are you doing a clean install, upgrading or installing onto another disk?)

The file `/etc/passwd-` would be a backup of `/etc/passwd`. The only reason for the chmod to fail I can think of is if the file doesn't exist, maybe it doesn't exist on your system, but the installer assumes it does.

Do

```
$ ll /etc/passwd-
```

and if it doesn't exist, create it:

```
$ sudo cp /etc/passwd /etc/passwd-
```

and then try the install again, what happens now?

Comment: I was attempting a fresh install from the ubuntu 12.04 burnt on a DVD disc. 
The file passwd- already exists.

Comment: Okay, I burnt a new DVD with ubuntu 11.10 and it installed without any issue. Now I'm upgrading to 12.04 using update manager, and there seems no issue now. Thanks. I think 12.04 installation wasn't working because of faulty burning maybe!

Comment: OK, glad to hear it's working out.